# How can I use multiple servers for different routes in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, server, load

I have a nodejs app running on express server. Currently I am using express router for routing my apis. However this backend is being used by multiple apps in the frontend. I am thinking if some apis are being used a lot more than others then we may need to use multiple servers for different api routes based on the load on the server. For example I have two apis for getting players and coaches and I'd like to hit one server when `/api/player` is hit and the other when `/api/coach`. I am wondering what is the established way to do this in nodejs?

Comment: This seems a lot like a premature optimisation.

Comment: I think this is the concept of load balancing which is implicitly or explicitly done in your cloud.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I didn't completly understand, do you mean to say I should not be doing this at all? How do I tackle the problem of load balancing then? I just wanted to know the standard practice for this.

Comment: I'm saying that you probably shouldn't start adding that kind of complexity into your application until it actually turns out that: 1. there is actually a marked difference in usage; and 2. this is causing some measurable performance issue with your current configuration.